# selecting random numbers from set of numbers without repetition

Tags: scala

I want to select `X` numbers from `0....N-1` such that numbers which are selected are not repeated. I know that

```
val rand_pos = Seq.fill(X)(Random.nextInt(N))
```

generates random number with repetetion. Is there are elegant way to get required selected numbers without repetition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If N is not too big you could use `scala.util.Random.shuffle` to create a permutation of 0..N-1 and then take X elements :

```
scala.util.Random.shuffle(Range(0,N).toList).take(X)
```

Comment: How much can be considered 'big' here? @Harald

Comment: That depends of course on your application requirements. `Range.toList` will create a list with N elements, an `shuffle` will create another one of the same size. So for example for N = 10^6 such a list will require 4 MB. This might be ok if you need that only once, but be too much when you do this repeatedly.